# How to create custom post listing in the admin?

Tags: custom-post-types, listing

I want the defult CPT listing to include not all posts but only some, according to a specific taxonomy.
is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This trick should help you...

```
<?php
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_posts_list');
function filter_posts_list($query)
{
    //$pagenow holds the name of the current page being viewed
    global $pagenow;
    $post_type = $query->get('post_type');

    //Check the post type and whether its the list page, then set the taxonomy
    if($post_type == 'my_cpt' && 'edit.php' == $pagenow)
    {
        //global $query's set() method for setting the taxonomy
        $query->set('my_taxonomy', 'my_taxonomy_value');
    }
}
?>
```

You can use any WP_Query parameters with the `set` method to modify this solution. For a detailed explanation, [hit this](http://blog.rutwick.com/display-only-the-posts-authored-by-the-current-wp-user-on-the-posts-page-in-the-back-end).

Comment: one error in the if up there. couldn't edit coz it's just one char

Comment: Ohh... typo... fixed it!